# Matplotlib error with colormap in version 1.5.0

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a python script, I just upgraded my matplotlib to 1.5.0 and am now getting this error:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
from matplotlib import rcParams
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, maskoceans
    cs = m.contourf(x,y,mask_data,numpy.arange(min_range,max_range,step),cmap=PRGn_10.mpl_colormap)
NameError: global name 'PRGn_10' is not defined
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a `matplotlib` error. The error message says that the name `PRGn_10` is not defined — because you never defined it. It is not present in any of your imports, and it is not a built-in, so Python cannot find it.

I am guessing you wanted to use the `PRGn` colormap. In order to do so, you need to import it, or the whole `colormap` module and reference it properly:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
cs = m.contourf(x,y,mask_data,numpy.arange(min_range,max_range,step),cmap=cm.PRGn)
```

or

```
from matplotlib.cm import PRGn
cs = m.contourf(x,y,mask_data,numpy.arange(min_range,max_range,step),cmap=PRGn)
```

Not sure what you meant by the `.mpl_colormap` bit, colormaps do not have such attribute.